# Table row height value different from the actual display height in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, html-table

I've got an interesting issue here around the height of the rows in a table that I'm using to display messages.  The requirements state that, if there are more than 7 messages, the entire `div` that contains the table should resize to the height of the 7 messages, and turn on a scroll bar on, to enable the viewing of the rest.

In the JS code (JQuery), once the page is ready, it first applies an "even" class to every even row in the table.

**JS**

```
 var $table = $('#messageTable');
 $('tr:even', $table).addClass('even');
```

**Style**

```
.even {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;}
```

That processing and the applied class is the ONLY difference between the odd and even rows.

After that is done, it checks the number of rows in the table and, if there are more than 7, it captures the height of each individual row in the first 7, adds them together, sets the height of the parent div to that value, and adds the `scrolling` class to that div.

**JS**

```
var $allRows = $('#messageTable tr');

var $totalRowsHeight = 0;

if ($allRows.length > 7) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        $totalRowsHeight += $('#messageTable tr:eq(' + i + ')').outerHeight();
    }

    $('#messageTable ').closest('.msgSection').css({'height': $totalRowsHeight +'px'}).addClass('scrolling');
}
```

**Style**

```
.scrolling {overflow: auto;}
```

And here is the resulting HTML structure after all of that has been run:

```
<div class="msgSection scrolling" style="height: 266px">
    <table summary="This table shows your messages" id="messageTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="messageDateWidth">03/14/2013</td>
                <td class="messageWidth">
                    <a name="message_01" href="TARGET_URL_HERE">D000012348</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <td class="messageDateWidth">03/13/2013</td>
                <td class="messageWidth">
                    <a name="message_02" href="TARGET_URL_HERE">C000012347</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="messageDateWidth">03/12/2013</td>
                <td class="messageWidth">
                    <a name="message_03" href="TARGET_URL_HERE">B000012346</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <td class="messageDateWidth">03/12/2013</td>
                <td class="messageWidth">
                    <a name="message_04" href="TARGET_URL_HERE">A000012345</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            . . .

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

So, all that works fine . . . the JS and CSS do just what they are supposed to do.  Except in Firefox (works in IE, Chrome, and Safari).

In Firefox, the `.outerHeight()` function returns a value of "38" for each row.  `.height()` and `.outerHeight(true)` also return "38".  When you examine the `<tr>` tags in Firebug, it says that they are 38 pixels tall. When you multiple that times 7, you get "266" (see the `style="height: 266px"` in the HTML above).

The problem is, the `<div>` is 4 pixels too long.

After doing some investigation, I discovered that Firefox is rendering all of the odd rows at **37** pixels tall (despite everything reporting that they are 38).  Since there are 4 odd rows in the first 7 rows, the height is calculating 4 pixels taller than the actual set of rows.

I've tried setting the odd rows to the "even" style (both manually through Firebug, and programatically through the console and, while the style applies, the height stays at the same 37 pixels (and still reports as 38).

I am officially stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a border-collapse property applied? if so, it would "lose" a pixel between rows if you have a 1px border applied. It's not considered in the inner height of the table cell, which could be why the heights vary. Add to that the potential of sub-pixel rendering that Firefox has capability of and it could very well be trying to display a height of 47.44... and it comes out as alternating 48/47. 
see: [Sub-Pixel Problems...](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/)

That really isn't an answer for you if you don't have borders on your table cells. Sorry.

Comment: That very well may be related.  Each row has a 1-pixel bottom border and the global table style is set to `border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;`.  Not sure why it would only affect the odd rows though.  Updating it in Firebug didn't seem to affect it, but I'll try updating the code with a style for this specific table and see if it fixes it on the page render (dev environment . . . can just change the code and hit 'reload'   :(   ).

Comment: Okay, I figured out a way to test it locally and resetting the table to use `border-collapse: separate;` and giving the table the attribute of `cellspacing="0"` seems to have stabilized the rendered height across the all browsers.  Of course, now I'm getting height calculation differences between them, but at least the rendering is consistent.  Much appreciated.   :)

Comment: Shoot . . . someone altered the JS with a Firefox-specific height calculation (in an attempt to solve this same issue) without telling me.  No initial affect with the new approach once I removed that.  I'll look into the "sub-pixel" issue next.  Thanks . . .

Comment: Okay, I started playing around with .offset on each of the rows as the code loops through and Firefox is very definitely "handling" 37.5 pixel heights for the row. Looks like you nailed it with the "alternating row height" issue.  Looks like I'm gonna have to figure-out some sort of hacky work-around.   :/   Thanks for pointing me down the right path. :)